# Is one supposed to grayscale and brightness contrast process the image before sending to AWS Textract?

Tags: amazon-textract

Textract results on recognizing basic arithmetic seems to degrade with color

This series of images show Textract **failing unusually in all cases except the one** where the image has been both grayscale and brightness/contrast (50/50 and 25/25)

- [unedited image from the camera](https://i.gyazo.com/0c6d8126dff5269dbe089a090a9e9d26.png) FAIL
- [brightness contrast applied without grayscale](https://gyazo.com/8e3cc523552449ff54b9ed8fdbe6594f) FAIL
- [grayscale](https://gyazo.com/8e3cc523552449ff54b9ed8fdbe6594f) FAIL
- [grayscale with brightness contrast](https://i.gyazo.com/22269131293c8e7b50c7aee7b998554c.png) finally!

Is one supposed to grayscale the image before sending to textract? Should one also apply brightness/contrast?

I assume Textract was trained with grayscale images - so should the service automatically convert the input images to grayscale?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Textract is an API that is built and tailored for document images, like scanned forms, bank statements, invoices, receipts. This is why you are getting sub-par results on your image.

For the type of documents you are trying to extract text from (post-it notes), the recommended API to use is [Amazon Rekognition DetectText API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detecting-text-procedure.html). This API deals with text recognition in the wild, like license plate, signs, short notes, shop front, etc. The main constraint of that API is that it only supports up to 100 words.

Here is a short snippet on how to use the API:

```py
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
    client = session.client('rekognition')

    response = client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': document_name}})

    textDetections = response['TextDetections']
    for text in textDetections:
        print('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
        print('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
        print('Type:' + text['Type'])
        print()
```

Comment: have you tried detectext aka rekognition - it was terrible at numbers and arithmetic opreators... has that been updated yet ?

Comment: It has improved since last year, but it is not geared towards mathematical operations. If you really care about mathetical operation transcription I can recommend this tool: https://mathpix.com/ which I found to work really well, even for more complex mathematical expression.